# Reform this canvas drawing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have a canvas which is divided into four portions as shown in the code snippet below and in each portion we can draw a circle with title. Can you please tell me that how to do this in such a way there is no overlapping between two circle or there heading. As you can see in the code snippet below that the names of the countries are overlapping and I doesnot want that. If there is an other way through which I can achieve this please suggest me. Thanks

Here is the code for my html:

```
<div id = "canvasContainer">
    <canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480"></canvas>
</div>
```

Css for the above html:

```
.canvasContainer{
    postion: relative;
}
.divtag{
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divtag1{
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```js
   
 var jsondata = [{"country": "Russia", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Israel", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Italy", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "France", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Spain", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "U.S.", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "India", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Saudi Arabia", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Mexico", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Brazil", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Philippines", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "UK", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Sweden", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Korea", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Japan", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "avoiding"},
  {"country": "Netherlands", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Germany", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Denmark", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Denmark", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Denmark", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Denmark", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Denmark", "cat1": "unexpressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
  {"country": "Antigua and Barbuda", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
{"country": "Albania", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
{"country": "United Arab Emirates", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"},
{"country": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "cat1": "expressive", "cat2": "confrontational"}];



window.onload = function(){
var canvas = null;//To get canvas element from the dom
var ctx = null; //To draw circle and label on the canvas
var CanvasWidth=0;//Total Width of the Canvas
var CanvasHeight=0;//Total Height of the Canvas
var ConvasContainer=null;//To add div to the start and end of  vertical and Horizontal Line 
var AxisText;//To add country name on the top of each circle

var MidX;//Mid point of the canvas w.r.t x-axis
var MidY;//Mid point of the canvas w.r.t y-axis
var colorName;//Color of the canvas circle
var colorArrays = ["#000000","#FF0000","#0000FF","#00FF00","#FF00FF","#800080"]; //All Colours for the circle

ConvasContainer=document.getElementById("canvasContainer");
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
CanvasHeight=canvas.offsetHeight;
CanvasWidth=canvas.offsetWidth;
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.beginPath();
//Drawing the vertical line 
ctx.moveTo(CanvasWidth/2, 0);
ctx.lineTo(CanvasWidth/2, CanvasHeight);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.beginPath();
//Drawing horizontal Line
ctx.moveTo(CanvasWidth,CanvasHeight/2);
ctx.lineTo(0, CanvasHeight/2);
ctx.stroke();

//Adding CONFRONTATIONAL to the left of horizontal line
AxisText=document.createElement("div");
AxisText.innerHTML="CONFRONTATIONAL";
AxisText.className="divtag";
AxisText.style.top=((CanvasHeight/2)-25)+"px";
canvasContainer.appendChild(AxisText);

//Adding AVOID CONFRONTATIONAL to the right of horizontal line
AxisText=document.createElement("div");
AxisText.innerHTML=" AVOID CONFRONTATIONAL";
AxisText.className="divtag";
AxisText.style.top=((CanvasHeight/2)-25)+"px";
AxisText.style.left=(CanvasWidth-130)+"px";
canvasContainer.appendChild(AxisText);

//Adding EMTIONALLY EMPRESSIVE TO THE TOP OF  Y axis
AxisText=document.createElement("div");
AxisText.innerHTML="EMTIONALLY EXPRESSIVE";
AxisText.className="divtag";
AxisText.style.left=((CanvasWidth/2)-70)+"px";
AxisText.style.top="0px";
canvasContainer.appendChild(AxisText);

//Adding EMTIONALLY UNEMPRESSIVE TO THE Buttom OF  Y axis
AxisText=document.createElement("div");
AxisText.innerHTML="EMTIONALLY UNEXPRESSIVE";
AxisText.className="divtag";
AxisText.style.left=((CanvasWidth/2)-70)+"px";
AxisText.style.top=(CanvasHeight-40)+"px";
canvasContainer.appendChild(AxisText);

MidX=((CanvasWidth/2));
MidY=((CanvasHeight/2));


//For adding circle and Text Between CONFRONTATIONAL AND EMTIONALLY EXPRESSIVE 
var Xvalue=29;
var Yvalue=70;
var Inc0=Yvalue;

//For adding circle and Text Between  EMTIONALLY EXPRESSIVE AND AVOIDING 
var X1value=MidX+40;
var Y1value=70;
var Inc=40;

//For adding circle and Text Between CONFRONTATIONAL AND EMTIONALLY UNEXPRESSIVE 
var x2value=35;
var y2value=MidY+50;
var Inc1=MidY+50;
//For adding circle and Text Between EMTIONALLY UNEXPRESSIVE AND AVOIDING 
var x3value=MidX+40;
var y3value=MidY+10;
var Inc3=40;

for(i=0;i<jsondata.length;i++)
{
 var index=getRandomIndex(0,colorArrays.length-1);
 colorName=colorArrays[Math.trunc(index)];
  
 if(jsondata[i].cat1==="expressive"&&jsondata[i].cat2==="confrontational")
 {
  DrawCircle(Xvalue,Yvalue,colorName);//For Drawing cicle
  Drawlabel(Xvalue-20,Yvalue-15,jsondata[i].country);//To Write country name above the circle
  
  if((Xvalue+60)<(MidX-15))
  {
   Xvalue=Xvalue+60;
   Yvalue=Yvalue+30;
  }
  else if((Yvalue+30)<MidY)
  {
   Xvalue=20;
   Inc0=Inc0+30;
   Yvalue=Inc0;
  }
 }
 else if(jsondata[i].cat1==="expressive" &&jsondata[i].cat2==="avoiding")
 {
  DrawCircle(X1value,Y1value,colorName);//For Drawing circle
  Drawlabel(X1value-20,Y1value-15,jsondata[i].country);//To Write country name above the circle
  
  if((X1value+60)<(CanvasWidth-15))
  {
   X1value=X1value+60;
   Y1value=Y1value+20;
  }
  else if((Y1value+30)<MidY)
  {
   X1value=MidX+60;
   Y1value=70+Inc;
   Inc=Inc+Inc;
  }
 }
 else if(jsondata[i].cat1==="unexpressive" &&jsondata[i].cat2==="confrontational")
 {
  DrawCircle(x2value,y2value,colorName);//Fot Drawing Circle
  Drawlabel(x2value-30,y2value-15,jsondata[i].country);//To Write country name above the circle
  
  if((x2value+60)<(MidX-15))
  {
   x2value=x2value+60;
   y2value=y2value+15;
  }
  else if((y2value+30)<CanvasHeight)
  {
   x2value=30;
   y2value=Inc1+30;
   Inc1=Inc1+30;
  }
 }
 else if(jsondata[i].cat1==="unexpressive" &&jsondata[i].cat2==="avoiding")
 {
  DrawCircle(x3value-3,y3value+20,colorName);//For Drawing Circle
  Drawlabel(x3value-20,y3value+3,jsondata[i].country);//To Write country name above the circle
  
  if((x3value+60)<(CanvasWidth-15))
  {
   x3value=x3value+60;
   y3value=y3value+20;
  }
  else if((y3value+30)<CanvasHeight)
  {
   x3value=MidX+60;
   y3value=MidY+Inc3;
   Inc3=Inc3+Inc3;
  }
  
 }
}

function getRandomIndex(min, max) {
return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function DrawCircle(x,y,color)
{
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(x,y,4,0,2 * Math.PI);
 ctx.fillStyle = color;
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.strokeStyle = color;
 ctx.stroke();
}

function Drawlabel(left,top,countryname)
{
 AxisText=document.createElement("div");
 AxisText.innerHTML=countryname;
 AxisText.className="divtag1";
 AxisText.style.left=left+"px";
 AxisText.style.top=top+"px";
 canvasContainer.appendChild(AxisText);
}
}
```

```css
.canvasContainer
{
    postion: relative;
}

.divtag
{
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divtag1
{
    position: absolute;
    background: none;
    font-size: 15px;

    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
 
}
```

```html
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Countries</title> 
</head>
<body>
<div id = "canvasContainer">
 <canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480"></canvas>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you could use ellipses and then, on hover, show the full name with a white background.

Comment: Neil thanks for your response using onhover in not according to my requirement. I want some solution that works according to my requirement.

Comment: In terms of scalability, I don't see how your specification makes any sense.  Eventually you're going to have points on the graph that overlap.  Even in your example if I were to move some of your texts to the bottom, then we would be running into a text beneath it.

Comment: This code is not 100% according to my requirement. What I want is to check if there any circle exist before drawing a new circle? First of all I decided to do it using the Math.random but in that circle overlap which i does not want.